# Finding two remarks in Dirac's 'The Principles Of Quantum Mechanics'

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Assuming it exists, could anyone point-out where I could find the phrase "Cesaro definition' in Dirac<sup>1</sup>. I have had a good look but cannot find it there. I also have been looking for where, I think he comments, about the normalization of a "scattering function" being insensitive to the functions form near to the scatterer ( hence origin of coordinates ), but cannot find this either.

This question is related to my working on the 'Delta Function Normalization' of the regular and irregular 'Coulomb Wave Functions', see at

[How do you work out, the 'Delta Function Normalization', of a 'Regular Coulomb Wave Function'?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4129194/)

and

[A problem with analysing the 'Delta Function Normalization', of an 'Irregular Coulomb Wave Function'.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4130849/)

See also

[Is this the way to 'Delta Function Normalise' a 'Continuum Wave Function'?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4153211/is-this-the-way-to-delta-function-normalise-a-continuum-wave-function)

[About the idea that, the “Normalization” of a “scattering wavefunction”, being insensitive to the functions form near to the scattering centre.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4132968/about-the-idea-that-the-normalization-of-a-scattering-wavefunction-being-i)

---

Reference

1. P.A.M. Dirac, The Principles Of Quantum Mechanics 4th Ed., Clarendon Press, Oxford, 1958

Comment: What leads you to believe that 'Cesaro definition' is mentioned by Dirac?

Comment: @Qmechanic  My memory.

Comment: I wonder if you mean [Ceásro Summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation).  Can't say whether it's in the reference you mention, but it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

I have looked some more for the rermarks, and have so far found one of them.

The phrase "Cesàro definition" can be found on pg. 95 of Dirac$^1$. I had looked in 'Ch VIII COLLISION PROBLEMS' and elsewhere, including pg 32, which if you look at the book's index, you will see, is where the 'Orthogonality Theorem' is mentioned.

In fact, the phrase is found in 'Section 23 The momentum representation', where Dirac$^1$ discusses, the failure of the orthogonality theorem for momentum eigenfunctions.

Dirac introduces a  new definition of what it means for a certain type of integral to converge. He says

> To bring the theory into order, we adopt a new definition of convergence of an integral whose domain extends to infinity analogous to the Ces$\grave{a}$ro definition of the sum of an infinite series.

With this new definition he says,

> the orthogonality theorem is restored

It seems to me that this is OK for momentum eigenfunctions, but possibly it still does not get restored, for problems involving scattering wavefunctions for a Coulomb potential.